# EditText setError is not staying on the box

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

Here is my setup

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/inputHintText"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textColor="#383838" />
```

and here is the java code

```
final EditText inputNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputNo); 

      inputNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        {

            if (s.length() > 2)
            {
            if (!s.toString().startsWith("ABCD"))
            {
                inputNo.setError( "Must start with ABCD" );
            }
            }

         }
    });
```

The code works fine and shows the red error message in the text box until keystroke 10. But lets say if the user still hits 11th key on the textbox then the error is going away and not staying on the textbox. 
One thing I realized that after the 10th input char is entered the afterTextChanged() method is not invoked meaning the addTextChangedListener is not really listening to input keys after the 10th chars because we have defined android:maxLength="10" in EditText.

How to resolve this? My desired result is that if the input do not start with "ABCD" then the error message stays on the edittext field until the user corrects it.

Any pointers/help appreciated!

Comment: I noticed this too.  In my case, it's not valid for the EditText value to be blank.  It would be more intuitive if the error stayed up until the user typed something.  Currently, it goes away when the EditText has no content and the user hits backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to limit EditText input:

```
TextView editEntryVew = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
editEntryView.setFilters(filterArray );
```

Comment: what did you mean by `FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);`?

Comment: I tried this and removed the max length constraint from my xml but I still see the error icon and message vanishing after the 10th stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you handle the delete key being pressed while the `EditText` is empty: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983097/832776

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when users input more texts than "maxLength" or delete an empty field. It seems to be an OS bug, I tried many ways and ended up with a workaround as below:

Suppose you have many textfields and a submit button, when users press submit, reset these textfields with their own texts to trigger validation again, such as:

```
textField1.setText(textField1.getText()) 
textField2.setText(textField2.getText()) 

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textField1.getError()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(textField2.getError())) 
        // submit
else 
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please correct invalid fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I hope this helps